# does closed under sequence limits imply the set is closed?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $T$ we have a set $F$ such that the limit of every convergent sequence of elements of $F$ is in $F$. can we deduce that $F$ is closed?

if $T$ be second countable then it's true, but what about the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having all limits of sequences in the set does not imply the set is closed. For instance, take an uncountable set with the cocountable topology. Then the only converging sequences are the eventually constant ones, and thus any set contains all limits of sequences in it. But of course not every subset is closed.